# Error- the task 'npm: watch' cannot be tracked. Make sure to have a problem matcher defined

Tags: npm, vscode-extensions

I tried running the Codepal Extension locally on my laptop to make some changes. I followed the steps that were told in the [file](https://github.com/IEEE-NITK/CodePal/blob/master/DEVELOPERDOCS.md). Please help me out to run it locally.

I tried using it locally by following the steps. But, I get error while trying to run it locally.

Comment: what kind of error did you get?

Comment: the task 'npm watch' cannot be tracked. Make sure you have a problem matcher defined.